# Submodule becoming "undefined" in Backbone.Marionette app

Tags: marionette

I'm making a Marionette app for uploading files and I'm at the very beginning of it. To start things off, I will show you the files I'm working with:

**upload_view.js**

```
AppManager.module("PrimaryApp.Upload", function(Upload, AppManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    Upload.UploadPage = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#upload-template"
    });
});
```

**upload_controller.js**

```
AppManager.module("PrimaryApp.Upload", function(Upload, AppManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
Upload.Controller = {
    show: function(){

        var uploadView = new Upload.UploadPage();

        AppManager.regions.primary.show(uploadView);
    },
  };
});
```

**app.js**

```
var AppManager = new Marionette.Application();

AppManager.on("before:start", function() {
    var RegionContainer = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        el: "#app-container",

        regions: {
            primary: "#primary-region",
            secondary: "#secondary-region",
            header: "#header-region"
        }
    });

    AppManager.regions = new RegionContainer();
});

AppManager.on("start", function(){
    console.log(AppManager);
    AppManager.PrimaryApp.Upload.Controller.show();
})

AppManager.start();
```

When running this application in a browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Upload' of undefined
```

For this line of code in app.js:

```
AppManager.PrimaryApp.Upload.Controller.show();
```

However, when I output AppManager to the console I get this:

[image]

Which shows that AppManager.PrimaryApp is indeed defined and contains all the submodules needed.  Any ideas why my AppManager.PrimaryApp is undefined when called as a function, but then is defined when outputted to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong!

```
AppManager.start();
```

Was in the wrong place and tried to run before AppManager.PrimaryApp was defined.  However,

```
console.log(AppManager);
```

was somehow called after AppManager.PrimaryApp was defined resulting in a correct output.  A simple move of my start() function fixed the order of things.